# Sumar los elementos de dos listas con listas

Tags: python

como puedo sumar los elementos de dos listas. He intentado esto pero sin éxito ya que requiere que las dos listas tengan el mismo número de elementos:

```
lista1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
lista2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]

lista3 = []

for i, w in enumerate(lista1):
    lista3.append(lista1[i] + lista2[i])

print(lista3)
```

Gracias y un saludo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que buscas es terminar con una lista del tamaño de la mayor pero con los elementos que comparten el índice sumados, puedes hacer una ligera modificación a tú código:

```
mayor, menor = (lista1, lista2) if len(lista1) > len(lista2) else (lista2, lista1)
lista3 = []
for i, _ in enumerate(mayor):
    if i + 1 > len(menor):
      lista3.append(mayor[i])
    else:
      lista3.append(mayor[i] + menor[i])

print(lista3)
```

Básicamente:

- Establecemos en primer lugar cual es la lista mayor para iterar por la misma
- En el ciclo si el índice supera la longitud de la lista menor, simplemente copiamos el elemento de la mayor, sino sumamos el elemento correspondiente al índice de las dos listas

Nota: En `for i, _ in enumerate(mayor):` usamos `_` para ignorar uno de los elemento recibidos del `enumerate`, justamente el que no vamos a usar, es una buena práctica hacerlo así.

Adicionalmente, una forma más simple de resolver este problema es:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

result = [sum(n) for n in zip_longest(lista1, lista2, fillvalue=0)]
print(result)
```

Usando [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest), que no es más que un [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) normal pero que tiene en cuenta cual es la lista más grande, lo que logramos es combinar ambas listas creando "parejas" y agregando un 0 para los elementos de la lista más pequeña (`fillvalue=0`), nos quedaría algo así:

```
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8), (5, 0), (6, 0)]
```

Así, podemos aplicar un `sum` sobre cada tupla sin problemas obteniendo el resultado esperado.

Answer (score 0):

para sumar la lista1 que tiene mas elementos que la lista2, puedes ingresar los elementos de la lista1 a la lista3 y luego sumar a cada elemento los de la lista2

```
    lista1 = [1,3,5,7,9,11]
    lista2 = [2,4,6,8,10]
    lista3 = []

    for i in range(len(lista1)):
      lista3.append(lista1[i])

    for i in range(len(lista2)):
      lista3[i] = lista3[i] + lista2[i]

    print(lista3)
```

Así te daria como resultado: [3,7,11,15,19,11]

para usar esto en otras listas con distinta cantidad de elementos puedes evaluar el largo de ambas y luego hacer el procedimiento que te propuse

```
    lista1 = [1,3,5,7,9,11]
    lista2 = [2,4,6,8,10]
    lista3 = []

    x = len(lista1)
    y = len(lista2)

    if (x > y):
      for i in range(x):
         lista3.append(lista1[i])
      for i in range(y):
         lista3[i] = lista3[i] + lista2[i]
    elif (x < y):
      for i in range(y):
         lista3.append(lista2[i])
      for i in range(x):
         lista3[i] = lista3[i] + lista1[i]
    elif (x == y):
      for i in range(x):
         lista3.append(lista1[i]+lista2[i])

    print(lista3)
```